# Unable to create tables in DB2 11.1 installed on Linux VM

Tags: create-table, db2-luw, db2-11

I am trying to create a 'employee' table in DB2 11.1.4.6.
However getting -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Installed Db2 11.1 on Linux. Also created 'professional' schema.

Below is the error :-

[db2inst3@DB2101 ~]$ db2 create table professional.employee(id int);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute a create table in the bash shell, not in a query utility for DB2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around the actual statement:

```
db2 "create table professional.employee..."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found it minutes after posting it. I was about to delete my posting..

Comment: [db2inst3@DB2101 ~]$ db2 "CREATE TABLE TABLE1(id int, name varchar(50),jobrole varchar(30),joindate date, salary double)"